# Invalid data from GPS (Ublox LEA-6T), would like it to be valid

Tags: gps, nmea, ar.drone

I have recently started a quadcopter project where my end goal is to fly a quad with DGPS. I am just in the beginning stages of this goal and have recently purchased a GPS but am having problems with the data I receive from it.

At present I have a ublox LEA-6T that I hope to mount on my drone. However, the GPS is not giving me valid data; it is finding satellites in view yet provides no fix. Here is an example of what I am receiving:

```
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
$GPGS99,,,,,,*48
$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
$GPGSV,3,1,12,01,,,22,02,,
$GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N*53
$GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
$GPGGA,,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*48
```

Can anyone offer any advice on how to get valid data? I have downloaded u-center but am unsure what to change to get a fix.
I would greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: Connect the antenna, and go out under free view to sky and wait some minutes. The very first time it may need 30minutes, next time only 30-45 seconds-

Answer (score 0):

This, *that*, is the return of a gps that does not have a fix.

There can be a number a reasons.  The two main reasons are:

[Time to first fix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix), or

No signal.  (Location or antenna problems.)

If giving it time doesn't rectify the problem consider location or hardware issues.

This is an example...https://superuser.com/questions/736939/cgps-gps-timeout-sierra-wireless

> Turns out the problem was that the antenna that was purchased was only
>   half of a GPS antenna.